# Compress a folder using tar in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, compression, tar

I try compress a folder in MATLAB using tar. I want to assign the current date as the name of the archive file. When I try

```
tar 'datestr(now)' FooFolder
```

Nothing happens. With

```
tar datestr(now) FooFolder
```

the name of the archive file is datestr(now).tar as expected. What is the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation is quite clear, use the [function syntax](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/syntax.html):

```
tar(tarfilename,files)
```

Example:

```
tar(datestr(now),'FooFolder')
```